# read images from zipfile in python throwing errors

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i am trying to get metadata from images inside a zip file. and it's throwing this error:
`PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000157389C2130>`

here is my code:

```
import zipfile
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
from io import BytesIO

with zipfile.ZipFile("samples.zip", "r") as f:
    for name in f.namelist():
        image_data = f.read(name)
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
        exif_data = image.getexif()
        width, height = image.size
        print(width, height)
```

i tried every solution i could find and still get the error. please help

Comment: Are you certain that the zip archive only contains files that represent images that **Image** can handle? I suggest unzipping your archive in a terminal and taking a look at what you get

Comment: Try adding `print(image_data[:20])` after reading so you can see what you've got.

Comment: @DarkKnight that was the problem !!  thank you so much!!